# CQ5 dispatcher alternative

Tags: aem, sling

Is there any alternative of dispatcher?

We cannot set headers from CQ5 with using dispatcher. Handling cookies is also tricky, we can store cookies, only with  POST request with using dispatcher. (storing cookies on client side is a bad practice).

So is there any better alternative for dispatcher, like caching in filter chain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's not really an alternative but a possible extension:

https://www.varnish-cache.org/

Comment: Sounds good!

I just found this link about varnish + cq5: http://www.slideshare.net/StefanMaurer/become-happier-by-using-varnish-cache

Thanks!